# collection of variant of words using special symbols

Tags: java, algorithm, text, data-structures, text-mining

I am working on a project related to spam filtering. Many of you might be aware of this technique used by spammers:

1. writing "items" as "|tem" (pipe instead of i)
2. $ale instead of sale
3. h0t instead of hot (zero instead of letter 'o')

etc. etc.

I am wondering if there is a database available for all such possible variants of words using special symbols? Or does any one know about some good strategy to tackle this trick?

Currently what I have done is, I simply replace '@' with 'a', '|' with 'i', '$' with 's' and so on. I need your views on this issue! Please help.

Comment: Please present any idea/suggestion whatsoever you have in your mind before voting to close the questions :(!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are taking a message as a starting point and trying to transform it.

Another aproach could be to start by defining a list of words which are likely to be changed (sale, viagra, etc) and then generate all possible similar words. As a measure of similarity you can take a Levenshtein distance.

Comment: thanks :)! I never thought about Levenshtein distance! If I use a dictionary I can get a list of possible words for the modified words and then I should somehow select the best one!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, however it is just a simple idea - there must have been a lot of research in spam detection. I think http://scholar.google.be/scholar?q=spam is the most appropriate source here.